# Can I use a hashed password as the secret for generating a hmac?

Tags: web-services, security, rest, authentication, hmac

I think it would be very comfortable to use the user's password hash as the secret for generating a hmac. Why is OAuth and others using tokens and nonces?

I think of something like this:

Client enters a password in the ui.
The application registers with the webservice using the hash of that password, which is stored on the server.
Form now on that hash hasn't to be transmitted again.
The client can always regenerate the secret by asking the user to enter the password and hashing it. Every message is signed with this hash, the server can look it up by username or guid and check if the sent mac is valid.

A intruder on the server can get that hash, but doesn't know the users real password, anyway he could send valid request with that hash. But this is not likely to happen, the saved hashes could also be hashed again using a nonce. Anyway because the pwd-file will be on a client's server it should be obfuscated using e.g. base64 to avoid the file looking like {"password":"a4bd146hashhashhash"}.

Most of all the real password of the user won't ever be transmitted. The request's will be secured with a timestamp/token against replay (I recognize the purpose of the token here).

Sending a hash would be perfectly applicable for me because the client will never be a simple website with a  tag e.g.. The webservice will be used in a ajax-based application and a java desktop application, both of them capable of hashing strings...

What's wrong with that? It's so simple, more RESTFul than anything related to authentication, and i think yet effective. What am I missing?

Greets, kruemel

Comment: The OAuth token identifies the _application_, not the user that authorizes the application to act on his behalf. Nonces are a mechanism to prevent replay attacks, not one for authentication. Providing authentication based on the _hash_ of the user's password is the same as working with plaintext passwords.

Comment: I just don't get it. What would be a reasonable approach? I was reading the last few days about it and i can't find a RESTful solution which really is elegant, intuitive and straight forward...

Comment: Registration would be: Server sends nonce, Client hashes nonce+password and sends it to server, server stores the hashed password after checking the hash.

Comment: Are you sure you actually _need_ OAuth? Are you going to talk to an OAuth service on behalf of your users, or are you just building an API that your users will use to talk to you?

Comment: But what happens next? Will the client request a nonce each time, do the transformation to the hash sign the message with this hash and send the whole packe to the server?

Comment: I don't want to use OAuth, I just need a straightforward RESTful authentication

Comment: In fact we are bulding an API that is used by client applications also written by ourselfs, how ever for the sake of scalability the webservice should be restful.

Comment: So what is this whole question about? OAuth is specified the way it is, because it is solving the _very specific_ task of allowing one party to talk to a second party on behalf of a third party; this three-way authorization is the reason for most of its contrivedness. If you have only two parties (your user and your service), you don't need OAuth.

Comment: I never said I want to use OAuth ;-) Could you outline the process of registration and authentication in a RESTful webservice using hmacs for me? I am not restricted on any standards, I just want a clean implementation. And as you said there is no third party.

Comment: How about [this draft](http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-williams-http-rest-auth-00); Also [Google has lots to offer](https://www.google.com/search?q=restful+authentication+-ruby).

Comment: The draft is basicly empty. I don't know if you read it yourself but it says quite in the beginning (like any other draft) 'It is inappropriate to use Internet-Drafts as reference'. I read it anyway and can't find something like a flow explanation or something similiar. This draft is about the proposed headers. But using a sessions/ resources sounds good to me.